# How to create a polynomial that accepts vectors?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a problem with creating a polynomial function of arbitrary length in Matlab, that would work, when used with a vector as an argument.

I have to do an algorithm, that includes and returns a value of a polynomial.
Bellow is my code:

```
n = 4 % For simplicity, could be arbitrary positive integer
f = @(x) x.^[0:n] %Coefficients are 1 (for this example), if not, would be multiplied with vector of them
p = @(x) sum(f(x))  %My polynomial

>> p(5)
ans =
781
```

This goes as planed. But because I need a plot, I need my polynomial to be able to receive vectors of values and return them. But when I do this, an error pops up.
Example:

```
>>p([1 2 3 4])
Error using  .^ 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in @(x)x.^[0:n]

Error in @(x)sum(f(x))
```

What I want it to return is a vector of length 4 with values of my polynomial `[p(1) p(2) p(3) p(4)]`
I got around this by creating a values vector with a for loop, but am just wondering, is it possible to change my code, so this would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be easily fixed using a row and a column vector, instead of two row vectors:

```
p([1 2 3 4]')
```

and explicitly defining the dimension along which you want to take the summation:

```
p = @(x) sum(f(x), 2)
```

**Explanation**

Note that `.^` is an element wise operation. `p([1 2 3 4 5])` works, because both row vectors have the same size, but doesn't return the desired result, i.e. it calculates `1^0 + 2^1 + 3^2 + 4^3 + 5^4 = 701`.

Matlab automatically expands (*in pseudo matlab code*)

```
[1  .^ [0 1 2 3 4]
 2
 3
 4]
```

to

```
[1 1 1 1   .^ [0 1 2 3 4
 2 2 2 2       0 1 2 3 4
 3 3 3 3       0 1 2 3 4
 4 4 4 4]      0 1 2 3 4]
```

**Backward compatibility (2006-2016a)**

The definition of `f` should be changed because matlab does not support [automatic arithmetic expansion](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) yet.

```
f = @(x) bsxfun(@power, x, 0:n);
```

**Backward compatibility (1996-2005)**

`bsxfun` didn't exist yet, so one should resort to `repmat`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got the same error as before.

Comment: Which matlab version are you using?

Comment: I am using Matlab version R2015b

Comment: I added backward compatibility fixes, original post assumed R2016b or newer.